# Calculating the right scaling for second Y axis on ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scaling

I am analysing the potential correlation between Unemployment Rate and Crime Occurrencies over a 22 months period (Jan 2019 - Oct 2020) across 9 English regions.

I am trying to plot a faceted linegraph with the following characteristics from two different data frames, **crime_count** and **unemployment_data**, respectively:

**X axis:** Date (both dataframes share the same time period)

**Y1 axis:** Crime Occurrencies (from crime_count)

**Y2 axis:** Unemployment Rate (from unemployment_data)

**Color:** Type of crime (from crime_count)

I succesfully plotted them using the code below, however I am struggling with the sec_axis() bit, as explained at the end of the post.

```
#This was needed to aggregate all crime occurrencies, which were
#categorical variables in the original dataset "crime_data" 

crime_count<-crime_data %>%
count(Region, Date, Crime, name = 'Crime_occurrencies')

#I tried calculating the right scaling as suggested in another discussion
#as follows

out_range <- range(crime_count$Crime_occurrencies)
in_range <- range(unemployment_data$unemployment_rate)

#Then I plotted it as follows:

ggplot(mapping=aes(Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Crime_occurrencies, colour = Crime), 
            data = crime_count) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(Date, Unemployment_rate, linetype = "Unemployment Rate"),
            col = "black", data = unemployment_data) +
  facet_wrap(~Region,
             scales = "free_y") +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2020-10-01"), by="1 month"),
               date_labels = '%m %Y') +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ rescale(.x, to = in_range, from = out_range))) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle =- 90, vjust = 0.5))

  #This line is what I am struggling with the most, because it does not scale
  #The second Y axis (Unemployment Rate) properly, as shown in the screenshot
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ rescale(.x, to = in_range, from = out_range)
```

I need the black line not to follow the scaling on the left Y axis (Crime Occurrencies) but the right one (Unemployment Rate).

Since the Unemployment Rate fluctuates between 0% and 6%, the black line representing it looks almost flat as it follows the scaling of the Crime Occurrencies axis for some reason (were the values are in the tens of thousands).

[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?
Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: after applying the suggestion provided by teun, this is the result:

[image]

It works perfectly for some graph, for others (such as the first row of graphs) the scaling is a bit off for the Crime Occurrencies now?

EDIT 2: added what teun suggested, and here is the result!

[image]

Comment: In your second `geom_line()`, you'd need `y = rescale(Unemployment_rate, to = out_range, from = in_range)` instead of `Unemployment_rate`, I think

Comment: It works! Thank you so much, you're a life saver!! Submit this as an answer and I'll accept it :D

Comment: Oh wait something is off with some graphs, let me show in the main post

Comment: No need, I already put this in my previous answer! :D Maybe it was forgotten when you refactored your code :) Where is the main post?

Comment: Just updated it!

Comment: Yeah that is the problem I had predicted would happen in my previous answer (see last bit of text there). Easiest fix would be to set `out_range[2] <- 20000` or some other value that fits across all facets.

Comment: That did the job! Every graph looks much clearer now. London is a bit off but that's no big deal, the other ones look great. Thanks again! I may ask, do you know how to change that "linetype" legend? I can only change what's underneath it but I cannot rename it itself

Comment: Either `+ labs(linetype = "Pretty name")` or `+ scale_linetype_discrete(name = "Pretty Name")` would do probably.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you think lockdown lead to an increase in anti-social behaviour?

Comment: Those spikes in anti-social behaviour coincide with the anti-masks protests that were going on across England (and especially London) I think. Unemployment rate seems unlikely to have a significant impact on crime rate here. Been trying to use both the commands you suggested and  scale_linetype_manual(name= "Pretty Name") but no matter where I type it,  when I try to run the command it cannot find Unemployment_rate to plot the line. Even though data = is specified. It works perfectly if I only type linetype = " Pretty Name", but that "linetype" in the legend doesn't look pretty at all haha

Comment: Are you trying to add it in another function? I meant to `+` it to the ggplot just like a `geom_*`. Like so: `ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + geom_line(aes(linetype = "A")) + labs(linetype = "Pretty name")`

Comment: If I add it after geom_line and not within aes() it does not appear at all, even though the command runs smoothly. So far the only way it shows is by typing linetype = "ABC" within aes(), before col = and data = ),

Comment: I'm confused now. You are trying to change the title of the legend right? Did the `+ labs(...)` suggestion not work?

Comment: yes, if I add + labs () outside of aes(), as you suggested, nothing happens; the legend for Unemployment Rate simply disappears. It only appears if I add linetype = "ABC" inside aes(), but it won't let me change the legend title

Comment: The `+ labs(...)` shouldn't be in any function, it should be on it's own line just like you would add a new geom or facet. See the examples in `?labs`.

Comment: Ok I managed to make it work! Thanks again!!